# PromQL to calculate error rates with RabbitMq queues

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am using the Prometheus plugin for RabbitMq which tracks the number of published messages to different queues. I am interested in the following metric: `rabbitmq_queue_messages_published_total` which has a couple of labels, but I am interested in the `queue` label. In RabbitMq by default, each queue will have an error queue paired with it. So if the original queue is called `ConnectionQueue` there will be a `ConnectionQueue_Error` queue for the errors. So our instant vectors will look like this:

```
rabbitmq_queue_messages_published_total{queue="ConnectionQueue",...} : 5000
rabbitmq_queue_messages_published_total{queue="ConnectionQueue_Error",...} : 50
...
rabbitmq_queue_messages_published_total{queue="SomeOtherQueue",...} : 4000
rabbitmq_queue_messages_published_total{queue="SomeOtherQueue_Error",...} : 40
```

So, I want to calculate the rate of errors for each queue in the last 5 minutes. 
I have tried this query:

```
(sum by (queue)(rate(rabbitmq_queue_messages_published_total{queue=~".*(Errors)"}[5m]))) / (sum by (queue)(rate(rabbitmq_queue_messages_published_total[5m])))
```

But the problem is that it doesn't group only the two corresponding queues together. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `on` to group by the `queue` label as a `left join` operation

```
(sum by (queue)(rate(rabbitmq_queue_messages_published_total{queue=~".*(Errors)"}[5m]))) / on (queue) (sum by (queue)(rate(rabbitmq_queue_messages_published_total[5m])))
```